# API Gateway IAM role to access DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I am following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/) Tutorial

I have created a role and attached the `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` policy to it ...

[image]

**When I assign this role to Gateway API .... like this**

[image]

I keep getting this error ...

> Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have
>   permission to assume the provided role

Isn't the "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" policy that I have applied to my role "MyDynamoRole" enough to give Gateway API necessary permissions ?

Comment: This other similar tutorial has more details/screenshots, including covering IAM more:  https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Found a solution ....**

Under "Role --> Trust Relationship", I have added another service i.e. API Gateway ...

```
"apigateway.amazonaws.com"
```

and all good now ...

Comment: What does your final IAM policy JSON look like?

Answer (score 0):

For people that might be struggling to create a role via the console, the hack is to use EC2 or Lambda based IAM roles to create a generic role and then edit the Trust Relationships to have the service.

```
"apigateway.amazonaws.com"
```